# Any way to use insecured FTP connection (noTLS) on delphi?

Tags: delphi, ftp

I'm developing an android app using Delphi. I'm having a problem with my ftp server. For any reasson I don´t know, it only accepts standard ftp connections (With no TLS). I'm receiving *time out error* with this code:

```
function uploadfile(imagetoload:TBitmap;place_id:string):boolean;
var
  filename:String;
  url,imagepath:string;
  FTP: TIdFTP;
begin
  try
    try
      filename:='PPic-'+user_id+'-'+DateToStr(today)+TimeToStr(Today)+'.jpg';
      filename:=replacetext(filename,'/','-');
      filename:=replacetext(filename,':','-');
    imagepath:=system.IOUtils.TPath.Combine(system.IOUtils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath,filename);
      imagetoload.SaveToFile(imagepath);
      ftp := TidFTP.Create(Nil);
      ftp.Host:=FTPSERVER;
      ftp.Username:=FTPUSR;
      ftp.Password:=FTPPWD;
      ftp.Passive := True;
      ftp.ConnectTimeout := 6000;
      ftp.Connect;
```

I have tried to connect to the ftp server using filezilla and only accepts connections when I select plain ftp connection.

Is there any way to use insecure (No TLS) connections with TIdFTP?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think that's the default already. Why do you think TLS is the reason your code is failing? (Also, if it's _your_ server, why don't you just enable TLS, if you think that's the problem?)

Comment: Yes, no TLS is the default. You have to take extra steps to enable TLS, especially in FTP since it uses multiple connections. Your timeout is related to something else.  `Connect()` (potentially) sends many FTP commands, any one of them could be timing out. It is hard to diagnose this problem without knowing where the timeout is actually occurring - when establishing the socket connection, or when sending commands, or when reading responses. I would suggest attaching a `TIdLog...` component to the `TIdFTP.Intercept` property and log the activity to see just how far `Connect()` is getting

Comment: I think that TLS is the reason because when I try to connect using it with Filezilla, I get the "time out" but, when I change connection to standard plain (insecure), it works. I have been speaking with the CPD provider to know what happens and they don´t know neither... I'm going to try to find how to enable TLS in the server. Thanks.

Comment: I'm going to check the log of filezilla and then try to use Intercept. Let me check. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem with the ssl certificates on my servers so finally I have coded a php function in order to upload pictures.

Thanks for your support.